# jQuery append(): tag is closed before it should

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code where i retrieve data and i want to show the results in a bootswatch (bootstrap) superhero list group.

The code i've got is:

```
$('#eventos_stats').html('<h2>Events</h2>');
$('#eventos_stats').append('<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">'+response.numero_eventos+'</span>Total events</li>');
$('#eventos_stats').append('<li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">'+response.asistencia_eventos+'</span>Total attendees</li></ul>');
```

The problem is that the  closes for the first result, making the list group to look separated or divided instead of rendering the results together.

That is to say, the html displayed is:

```
<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">3</span>Número de eventos</li></ul>
<li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">245</span>Número de asistentes</li>
```

You can notice that the `</ul>` closes before, even if I append it at the end. Here is the problem. It should look like this:

```
<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">3</span>Número de eventos</li>
<li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">245</span>Número de asistentes</li></ul>
```

Why is this happening? How can I make the  closing tag appear right at the end?

Comment: Ok, that did the trick. Thanks. The bad thing is that now I have a longer line. If i put a line break, the code crashes by saying "Illegal token".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply change the second append to append to the class of the unordered list

```
$('#eventos_stats').html('<h2>Events</h2>');
$('#eventos_stats').append('<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">'+response.numero_eventos+'</span>Total events</li>');
$('.list-group').append('<li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">'+response.asistencia_eventos+'</span>Total attendees</li></ul>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how append works - you must append entire elements in each call. You cannot append the opening tag of an element in once call, then close it in another.

Try this:

```
$('#eventos_stats').append('<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">'+response.numero_eventos+'</span>Total events</li><li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">'+response.asistencia_eventos+'</span>Total attendees</li></ul>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your third line can be

```
$('#eventos_stats ul').append('<li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">'+response.asistencia_eventos+'</span>Total attendees</li>');
```